# read an xslx file and convert to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xlsx

I have a xslx file with following data

```
    www.url.com
    www.url.com
    www.url.com
    www.url.com
    www.url.com
    www.url.com
    www.url.com
    www.url.com
    ...
```

Like you can see I have only 1 column used and a lot of rows.
I need to read that column from the xslx file somehow and convert it to `List<string>`.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), it's simple, something like this :

```
  var ep = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFile));
  var ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

  var domains = new List<string>();
  for (int rw = 1; rw <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rw++)
  {
    if (ws.Cells[rw, 1].Value != null)
     domains.Add(ws.Cells[rw, 1].Value.ToString());
  }
```

Comment: well to sort out the obvious, do you have Sheet1 in your excel ? And if you have one is it by some chance empty ?

Comment: I have followed this but it gives, cannot cover tfrom 'method group' to 'string'

Comment: at which line ? last one was missing brackets on ToString, fixed that

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)? Super simple to do.

```
        var wb = new XLWorkbook(FileName);

        var ws2 = wb.Worksheet(1);

        List<string> myData = new List<string>();

        foreach (var r in ws2.RangeUsed().RowsUsed())
        {
            myData.Add(r.Cell(1).GetString());
        }
```

Comment: I asked the question 10 years ago :') don't know anymore. Thanks for contributing

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way is to use OleDb, you can do something like this:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();

string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\your\\path\\file.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;\"";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [SheetName$]", conn);
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // this assumes just one column, and the value is text
            string value = reader[0].ToString();
            values.Add(value);
        }
    }
}

foreach (string value in values)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use OOXML to read the file and this library simplify your work http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com.