# Convert a list of object to a list of class

Tags: c#, excel, class, object

I have a excel file, I take data of this file to a list of object.I defined class which represent each line this excel file.
How may I convert this list of objects to a list of my class type?  I try this and I get an exception. Can anybody help me?

```
public class Mark
{
    public string Code { get; set; }//Equivalant d'IdEntreprise dans la table Reed_Exposant
    public string Marque { get; set; }
    public string Pays { get; set; }
    public string Identifiant { get; set; }//CleExtern coté API
    public string IsEc_MRK { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

}         
public List<object> Export(string path, string sheetName) => new 
ExcelQueryFactory(path).Worksheet<Object>(sheetName).ToList();


public IEnumerable<Mark> ExportExcel(string path)
{
    marques = Export(path, "Import").Cast<Mark>().ToList();
    return marques;
}
```

Comment: What exception do you get? Also, you can use `dynamic` type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read an xslx file and convert to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704582/read-an-xslx-file-and-convert-to-list)

Comment: Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'System.Object' en type 'REF.HistoriqueSalon.Entites.Mark'.